# Postgres No Primary Key Drawback

Tags: postgresql

Is there any drawback to not having a primary key for a table in Postgres?  Since all data is stored unordered in the heap anyway, is the primary key just a way to enforce a unique key and an index at the same time?  Or is there a fundamental feature that a primary key provides in a table as opposed to a table that does not have a primary key?

Comment: How would you handle updating a record in a table without a primary key?

Comment: Don't need to retrieve single rows and rows are never updated, only inserted.  Although the rows do have individual identities (UUID), they are only ever grabbed in ranges.  I have indexes on the ranges, but there is no point in having an index on the unique key if it can be avoided.

Comment: I am asking the specific question, because I come from a SQL Server background and deciding whether to have a clustered index on a table or a heap only table is an important decision to make.  With Postgres, this decision seems meaningless since the data is always stored unordered in the table to begin with.  However, I want to make sure that I am correct in this assumption.  What is the benefit   of a PK in Postgres vs, say a unique constraint and a separate index?  Is there any distinction or is it just a shorthand way to provide those features?

Comment: @Olaf Sometimes you don't need to update. Sometimes there can be a primary key in logical terms, but no `PRIMARY KEY` annotated in the DDL to save the overhead of an index in exchange for the lack of enforcement. I wouldn't do it but I can imagine situations in which it might apply.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Per the Postgres documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html):

> Technically, PRIMARY KEY is merely a combination of UNIQUE and NOT
>   NULL, but identifying a set of columns as primary key also provides
>   metadata about the design of the schema, as a primary key implies that
>   other tables can rely on this set of columns as a unique identifier
>   for rows.

From my experience, I have created plenty of tables without them. But some replication solutions require there be a primary key, or at the single column identifier per row.

Comment: Ah, good point about the replication issue.  That completely slipped my mind.  Although I do have a unique UUID in each row, I should make sure that no PK won't be a replication issue (no foreign keys for this so that's not a problem).  Thanks.

Comment: Another issue that pops to mind is that most ORMs (e.g. Django) have problems dealing with tables that don't have primary keys.  So, if ever need to put a UI on top of the table, then it may make life a bit tougher on whomever is working on it.  Not a huge deal, but might be a consideration (depending on the data and what's going on within your company/team).

Comment: A foreign key constraint requires a `UNIQUE` index on the target column(s). Doesn't have to be a primary key.

Comment: A specific case of replication issues is that logical decoding (introduced in 9.4) uses the PRIMARY KEY constraint to determine its behavior. Of note, the old value of the primary key is included in UPDATE and DELETE messages. A table with no primary key will only send out INSERTs on the logical decoding stream; UPDATEs and DELETEs are lost.

Comment: Reading the postgres docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/different-replication-solutions.html am I right to say that WAL Shipping doesn't require primary keys but Logical Replication does?